# Clearing value state in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, react-redux

Using an api endpoint that holds the an an array of objects for specific crypto currency coins.

I created a form where users can type in a specific coin and hit submit and it will return the price. That coin will then check if its in an array of object in the api. If it's valid then I push that into the filtered results array in the constructor.

My first search query works, but when I do my second query search and hit the submit button, it fails and just reloads the page.

```
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {value: ''};
     this.state = {coin: []};
     this.state = {items: []};
     this.state = {filteredResults: []};

     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    let coin = this.state.value;
    this.findCoin(coin);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  findCoin(id) {
    this.state.items.forEach(function(currency){
      if(currency.id === id) {
        this.state.filteredResults.push(currency)
      }
    }, this);

    this.setState({filteredResults: this.state.filteredResults[0]});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/`)
      .then((result)=> {
        result.json()
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({items: json})
       });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           <label>
             Name:
             <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
           </label>
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div> Price: $ {this.state.filteredResults.price_usd}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably doesn't matter to your problem, but the setting of state in your constructor probably wants to looks like this: `this.state = { value: '', coin: [], items: [], filteredResults: [] }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this method:

```js
findCoin(id) {
    this.state.items.forEach(function(currency){
        if(currency.id === id) {
            this.state.filteredResults.push(currency)
        }
    }, this);

    this.setState({filteredResults: this.state.filteredResults[0]});
}
```

At line

```
this.setState({filteredResults: this.state.filteredResults[0]});
```

you are setting `filteredResults` (which is an array) to an object and on the second search the line

```
this.state.filteredResults.push(currency)
```

gives you an error, as `filredResults` being a string doesn't have `push` method.

And as you have `event.preventDefault` on the last line of `handleSubmit` method it's not executing because of previous error and form is submitting.

Comment: On the second search, when i put a debugger statement, it looks like its still an object?

Comment: Edited it. Yes, it's a `currency` object, but not an array, as it's expected

Answer (score 0):

This method is mutating state, which circumvents React's state checking;

```
  findCoin(id) {
    this.state.items.forEach(function(currency){
      if(currency.id === id) {
        this.state.filteredResults.push(currency)
      }
    }, this);

    this.setState({filteredResults: this.state.filteredResults[0]});
  }
```

Use a method such as filter, that gives a new array reference:

```
const filtered = this.state.items.filter(ccy=> ccy.id === id);
this.setState({filteredResults: filtered[0]};
```

Also as one of the other posters has mentioned, declare the filterResults as an object (if you are only ever going to display one filtered result), as it changes from array to object.

```
this.state = {filteredResults: {}};
```

Comment: it's not the only problem here, there is also data type change from array to object